# add geom_bar to circular plot ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a data frame that looks like so:

```
dat<-structure(list(x = 1:14, y = c(1.26071476002898, 1.97600316441492, 
2.41629009067185, 3.48953782319898, 10, 8.49584395945854, 3.80688560348562, 
3.07092373734549, 2.96665740569527, 2.73020216450355, 2.39926441554745, 
2.4236111796397, 2.63338121290737, 2.13662243060685)), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")

x         y
1  1.260715
2  1.976003
3  2.416290
4  3.489538
5 10.000000
6  8.495844
7  3.806886
8  3.070924
9  2.966657
10  2.730202
11  2.399264
12  2.423611
13  2.633381
14  2.136622
```

I'm trying to create a circular plot in ggplot2 where the circle is divided into the 14 data points I have and the length of each of the arcs corresponds to the value of y. Something like this:[image]

My code produces a very weird output with the bars overlapping one another. I have searched everywhere to fix it but no success. Here is my code:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_bar(breaks = seq(1,14), width = 2, colour = "grey",         stat="identity") + coord_polar(start = 0) + scale_x_continuous("", limits = c(1, 14), breaks = seq(1, 14), labels = seq(1, 14))
```

Please help me… thanks in advance...

Comment: It's because you specified `width=2`.  This produces the overlap.  Also, you don't need any `breaks`.

Comment: @Andrie IMO you should post this as an answer, with the resultant output.

Comment: @jlhoward I found some time while my tests ran...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you specified `width=2`. This produces the overlap.

Note also that you don't need any `breaks`.

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_polar(start = 0) +
 scale_x_continuous("",breaks = seq(1, 14))
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I searched for, thank you! For anyone else looking for more easily customizable options, there is also the ggradar package: https://github.com/ricardo-bion/ggradar