# circle graph showing bearings and distance

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to show the bearings that individuals travelled away from a site and the distance travelled within 1 day, as well as the numbers of individuals travelling at different bearings.

Presently, I can make those basic plots in ggplot2:

```
# distance & bearing
ggplot(data=df,
       aes(bear, dist)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_log10()

# no. individuals & bearing
ggplot(data=df.postDepDT,
       aes(bear)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 36)

#my data looks like the following
bear <- c(-172, -175, -160, -155, -150, -10, 23, 87, 122, 179)
dist <- c(5, 101, 326, 47, 23, 55, 6, 7, 44, 162)
df <- data.frame(bear, dist)
```

I would like my final plot to have two panels. The first is a circle with points at different lengths (indicating distance) radiating away from the circle in the direction of the bearing.  These points would be connected to the circle along the bearing.  The second is a histogram around the circle, showing numbers of individuals moving away from a circle along each bearing.

In these figures 0o (or North) would be at the top at -180o/180o (South) would be at the bottom, with -90o and 90o (west and east) on the left and right, respectively.

UPDATE:

Adding coord_polar() to the figures helps make a circular figure, however, I'm still unable to get the 0o value (for North) at the top of the figure (start=0 puts the 0o value at the bottom). Also, I'm still looking for a solution to connect the points in the first plot to the centre point.

Comment: So what exactly is your question here? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @MrFlick I need a way to wrap the x axis, so that the graph is on a circular, rather than a flat plane.

Comment: `?coord_polar` is what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Axeman. That helps a lot, but the 0 value falls at the south end of both plots, rather than at the top (0 = N for my bearings). Do you know how to address that? Also, do you know how I can connect the centre of the plot to the points in the first plot?

Comment: Did you read `?coord_polar`? There is a `start` argument to set any arbitrary start ("north") value. You can use `geom_segment` to draw arbitrary lines for your second problem, or look up "lollipop plots".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add geom\_bar to circular plot ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204826/add-geom-bar-to-circular-plot-ggplot2)

Comment: @Axeman, when I try start=0, the 0 value ends up at the bottom of the figure.  I've tried other values for start (90, -90, etc.), but the result is very unpredictable.

Comment: @Lex, I'm not sure why you think this is a duplicate, the questions are very different.

Comment: @Axeman, can you provide an example for how geom_segment would work.  It is not clear to me.

Comment: @user3220999 apologies, I read them as similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

[image: illustration]

```
ggplot(data=df,
       aes(bear, dist)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = bear, yend = 0.1)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-180, 180),
                     breaks =  seq(-180, 180, 90)) +
  # scale_y_log10() +
  coord_polar(start = pi) +
  theme_bw()
```

**Explanations**:

1. `geom_segment()` expects aesthetics for `x`, `y`, `xend`, & `yend`. The "pre-`coord_polar`" version of a circular chart with lines radiating from the centre would have been a chart in Cartesian coordinates with lines that drop down vertically to intersect the x-axis, so we'd want each `xend` value to be the same as the `x` value, and each `yend` value to be the smallest possible (which would be 0 for distance, but since you are interested in the log scale for the y-axis, I've added a small positive value):

[image: cartesian form]

```
ggplot(data=df,
       aes(bear, dist)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = bear, yend = 0.1)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-180, 180),
                     breaks =  seq(-180, 180, 90)) +
  # scale_y_log10() +
  # coord_polar(start = pi) +
  theme_bw()
```

2. `coord_polar()` expects the following for its `start` argument (emphasis added):

> offset of starting point from 12 o'clock in **radians**

Since your bearing's actual values are in the `c(-175, 179)` range, I expect your scale to be `c(-180, 180)`. The default `start = 0` would thus place `-180/180` at the 12 o'clock position. To place `0` at the 12 o'clock position, set `start = pi`, which is 180 degrees in radians.

3. Lastly, I urge you to think through *why* you want to use the log scale to represent distance. On a technical level, the choice of an arbitrarily small positive value for `yend` can result in the same point appearing to be at different distances from the centre. (see illustration below for some `yend` values) On a more theoretical level, I understand log scale to be appropriate when we are comparing a large range of quantities, which isn't really the case here.

[image: illustrations with different yend values]

```
p <- ggplot(data=df,
       aes(bear, dist)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-180, 180),
                     breaks =  seq(-180, 180, 90)) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  coord_polar(start = pi) +
  theme_bw()

gridExtra::grid.arrange(
  p + geom_segment(aes(xend = bear, yend = 1)) + ggtitle("yend = 1"),
  p + geom_segment(aes(xend = bear, yend = 0.1)) + ggtitle("yend = 0.1"),
  p + geom_segment(aes(xend = bear, yend = 0.01)) + ggtitle("yend = 0.01"),
  p + geom_segment(aes(xend = bear, yend = 0.001)) + ggtitle("yend = 0.001"),
  nrow = 2
)
```

Comment: thank-you for the most comprehensive explanation to any question I've every posted.  I really appreciated the detailed explanation, as well as the helpful comments on the appropriateness of my choice.  One quick comment on the log scale, since my actual dataset spans 3 orders of magnitude, I will probably have to use a log scale, but I will consider the point you made above and make sure that value I select as yend, minimizes the distortion of the data.  Thank-you again!